# Drupal - How to get SUM of rows

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-7

I want to do a simple select with a SUM of several rows in Drupal, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. I know there are more ways to do a query in Drupal (one of them is writing the actual query, but I don't want that).

Here is the code I have:

```
$query = db_select("node","n");
$query->fields("n", array("nid","likes" => "SUM(likes)"));
```

But apparently Drupal strips my brackets and I get the following error:

```
1054 Unknown column 'n.SUMlikes' in 'field list'
```

Could anyone help me? Is there something like `$query->sum()`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'd be best off using an expression:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid'));
$query->addExpression('SUM(likes)', 'likes');
```

The first argument is the expression, the second the alias.

Hope that helps

Comment: And how can I access the result? $query->total?

Comment: //Following is the complete syntax worked for me
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid'));
$query->addExpression('SUM(likes)', 'likes');
$query->execute();